# Invert and convert slider value

Tags: actionscript-3, math

I currently have a vertical slider that is controlled by the user using startDrag.  The puck is restricted in movement by a track movieclip that is 115px high.

```
private function init():void
{
    puck.y = (track.height-puck.height)/2;
    puck.buttonMode = true;
    puck.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onMouseDown);
}
private function sendNewValue():void
{
    trace(Math.round(puck.y-track.y+(puck.height/2)));
    var newVal:Number = ; //need some math magic here
    dispatchEvent(new ToolEvent(ToolEvent.SCALE,1));
}
private function onMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onMouseUp);
    puck.startDrag(false,new Rectangle((track.x + (track.width/2))-(puck.width/2),track.y-(puck.height/2),0,track.height));
}
private function onMouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    puck.stopDrag();
    sendNewValue();
}
```

I can get a value from it using `Math.round(puck.y-track.y+(puck.height/2))`, which gives me values between 1 and 115 based on the position of the puck.

Now sadly maths is not my strong point at all (helpful for a programmer!), so would someone please explain how I can convert these values so that:

```
1 = 2
115 = 0
midpoint (115/2) = 1
```

**Edit:** kind of like the question here: [How do I reverse my sound volume math for my volume slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179869/how-do-i-reverse-my-sound-volume-math-for-my-volume-slider), but as well as inverting the value I need to adjust it on a scale.

Comment: what do you mean by 1=2 and 115=0 ?

Comment: at the moment I'm getting a range of values from my slider between 1 and 115. I need some cunning bit of maths that will spit out a number between 2 and 0 given the input from the slider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're looking for a  linear function such that:

```
f(1)=2 and f(115) = 0

F(x) = 115/67 -x/67 will work
```

**Generalization:**

If you looking for a linear function *f(x) = a.x + b* such that:

```
f(x1)=y1
f(x2)=y2
```

then the solution is:

```
a=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
b=y1 - x1*(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
```

Comment: you're welcome, I wrote a general solution so you can find the solution yourself in the future

Comment: Thanks again. For the record, the whole thing when applied to my code looks like this: `var outVal:Number = (track.height/(track.height/2))-((puck.y-track.y+(puck.height/2))/(track.height/2));`

Answer (score 0):

```
var sliderValue:Number = Math.round(puck.y-track.y+(puck.height/2));
var sliderPercent:Number = (sliderValue / 115);
var result = Math.abs((sliderPercent * 2) - 2);
```

Let me know if that works. I don't particularly understand the function above so that one might be better. In my code, 55 would give you 1.04 because its more than halfway to the full amount, which is in your case 0 instead of 2 being the full amount.