# Math equation for scaling number between two limits not starting at 0?

Tags: math

For example, I have a number between 1~100 and I need to scale it to be between 20~80.

Examples:

```
1 scales to 20
100 scales to 80
50 scales to 50
```

Comment: This question should be asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/
This forum is specific to programming.

Comment: Why does `50` scale to `40`? If this is a linear transformation, the result should be around `50`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math, not programmming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for a function f such that :

```
f(x) = ax +b

f(1)=20
f(100)=80
```

Then

```
a+b=20
100a+b=80
```

You get :

99a +20 = 80

```
then a =60/99=20/33
and b = 20 - 20/33 = 20*(32/33)
```

Have a look at this question for more information :

[Invert and convert slider value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496205/invert-and-convert-slider-value/6496369#6496369)

**Note:** if 50 scales to 40 your transformation is not linear. So you need to look for another type of function:

f(x) = ax**2 + b x + c

Comment: sorry sorry, it's a mistake, 50 scale to 50!

Comment: I used your linear equation and it works well!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user468384 you're welcome, you can have a look at the link I posted for a more general formula. Note that 50 doesn't exactly scale to 50 because you're not scaling (0,100) to (20,80) but (1,100) to (20,80)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific about what you're looking for. The rules you given do not produce a consistent LINEAR scaling.

For, if it were linear:

```
(1, 20) is on the line
(100, 80) is one the line
```

Slope is:

```
(80 - 20) / (100 - 1) = 60 / 99
```

Line is

```
y - 20 = (60 / 99) * (x - 1)
```

Then:

```
y = (60 / 99) * (x - 1) + 20
```

Then, testing `x = 50`:

```
y = (60 / 99) * (50 - 1) + 20 = 2940 / 99 + 20 != 40
```

Thus, there is no such LINEAR scaling.

Comment: Sorry, the 50 scaling is a mistake, it scale to 50!

Comment: Okay, well it's still not linear (but it's close (linear would be to scale it to 49.6969...)). If you tell me you scale to the nearest integer, then we are fine. Use exactly the method I just explained to discover the linear equation governing the scaling relationship.