# How do I take an array of numbers and 'fit' them into a min/max range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, numbers

I have a function that generates an array of values, like:

[343, 709, 88, 4, 0] = total of 1144.

The values generated by my function always add up to some set number **nMax** (in this case, 1144).

But now I *separate function* where I can pass an array of these values and fit them into a range determined by **nMin** to **nMax**, like refit(array, nMin, nMax).

Let's say nMin = 30, nMax = 1144.

For this example, that would mean I need 0 to become 30, and the rest of the numbers to proportionally get smaller, so that all of the numbers still add up to **nMax** (1144).

I tried creating a function based on a formula I found here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43698/range-scaling-problem) but it's not working:

```
var oldMin = 0; //constant
var oldMax = 1144; //constant

function refit(oldArray, newMin, newMax) {
    var newArray = Array(oldArray.length);
    for(var i=0; i < oldArray.length; ++i) {
        var oldValue = oldArray[i];
        var newValue = (newMin * (1 - ((oldValue - oldMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)))) + (newMax * ((oldValue - oldMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)));
        console.log(oldValue + ' = ' + newValue);
        newArray[i] = newValue;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

The output of this looks like:

```
343 = 364.00524475524475
709 = 720.4073426573426
88 = 115.6923076923077
4 = 33.89510489510489
0 = 30
```

Which is not correct, because the output adds up to *1264* which is not right.

Suggestions?

Comment: Other than implementing linear scaling?

Comment: Can you provide the function for getting the nMax array please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math equation for scaling number between two limits not starting at 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731257/math-equation-for-scaling-number-between-two-limits-not-starting-at-0)

Comment: How about something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/269BY/

Comment: @Leth0_, was hoping to have an entirely separate function that only accepts an existing array and refits it to nMin and nMax. The original function itself can't be changed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I just googled 'how to linear scale an array of numbers' but I'm not sure what I'm missing.